# Regex match following substring in string python

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7

I've come up with a regex expression that works well enough for my purposes for finding phone numbers.

I would like to take it a step further and use it in large text blocks to identify matching strings that follow the words 'cell' or 'mobile' by at most 10 characters.  I would like it to return the number in `Cell Phone: (954) 555-4444` as well as `Mobile 555-777-9999` but not `Fax: (555) 444-6666`

something like (in pseudocode)

```
regex = re.compile(r'(\+?[2-9]\d{2}\)?[ -]?\d{3}[ -]?\d{4})')
bigstring = # Some giant string added together from many globbed files
matches = regex.search(bigstring)
for match in matches:
    if match follows 'cell' or match follows 'mobile':
        print match.group(0)
```

Comment: are you just trying to ignore the fax numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
txt='''\
Call me on my mobile anytime: 555-666-1212 
The office is best at 555-222-3333 
Dont ever call me at 555-666-2345 '''

import re

print re.findall(r'(?:(mobile|office).{0,15}(\+?[2-9]\d{2}\)?[ -]?\d{3}[ -]?\d{4}))', txt)
```

Prints:

```
[('mobile', '555-666-1212'), ('office', '555-222-3333')]
```

Comment: this solution does not even work for the provided example `Cell Phone: (954) 555-4444` ... not because of the word Cell but because it does not match the first parenthesis

Comment: Yes. You can put whatever inside the first capture group. Play with it [here](https://regex101.com/r/jL0oL4/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with your regular expression. In the `re` documentation, you will find that the pattern `r'(?<=abc)def'` matches `'def'` only if it is preceded by `'abc'`.

Similarly `r'Hello (?=World)'` matches `'Hello '` if followed by `'World'`

Comment: I added that it needs to be able to match even if there are intermediate words or symbols - will this work for that?

Comment: it can work but you will have to adapt your regex a bit